# Ax=B has no solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the textbook it says that no solution would mean

$$
r<m
$$

If $\mathbf{A}$ is an $m$ by $n$ matrix. I didn't quite get that. 
We know that

$$
r\le n
$$

for all times right, but isn't $r$ always larger than $m$? since $r$ is the rank of the matrix, it is both the degree of the row space and the column space. if $r$ is the degree of the row space it is the degree of the column space of transpose of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$

The transpose of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is $n$ by $m$, which means it has $m$ columns. since $r$ is still the degree this would imply that

$$
r\le m
$$

So my question is why is it a requirement for

$$
r<m
$$

to have no solutions. there could easily be found cases where$$r<m$$ and has a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the equation:  $Ax=b$, has no solutions for some particular $b$.  (*having no solutions for all $b$ is just silly since $b=0$ one would always have at least one solution of $x=0$*).

This tells us that $Ax=b$ is an inconsistent system and that $\text{rref}(A|b)$ has a row of $[0,0,\dots,0\mid 1]$.  (*possibly also some rows of all zeroes too at the bottom*).

This tells us that $\text{rref}(A)$ has a row of all zeroes.

One of the interpretations of $rank(A)$ is the number of pivots present in the rows of $\text{rref}(A)$.  We know it can not be $m$ (*the number of rows*) since there is at least one row of all zeroes where no pivot can exist.  (*If it were $m$, then that would contradict that statement*).

Thus, $rank(A) < m$

---

Note: here, the hypothesis is that **given a vector $b$**, if $Ax\neq b$ for all $x$ then...

Although there are always some pair of $b$ and $x$ that will always give a solution (*e.g. both zero*), we are not interested in searching for a $b$, we are only interested in searching for an appropriate $x$.

Further, we are not interested in proving the converse (which is not logically equivalent).  $Ax=b$ has no solution $\Rightarrow r<m$ is what we want to prove.  We do not want to prove $r<m \Rightarrow Ax=b$ has no solution.  Certainly, there exist cases of $b$ with $r<m$ and solutions to $Ax=b$ existing.  (*again, take $b$ to be $0$ for trivial example*)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I got it now. Also thanks for the logical implementation. That helped me quite a lot.